# recording with uncompressed audio speeds up video

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, libavcodec, libav

I  have been using a recorder (based on muxer example) satisfactorily for quite some time for various formats. Now I need to use uncompressed audio to go with MJPEG video and I notice video speeds up considerable (like 10 times as fast) in the recorded file. Audio is OK, and if I use a compressed audio format (like mp3) video is fine as always. Does anyone have an idea why video speeds up the moment I use uncompressed audio (CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE)?